# Valgrind and macOS Big Sur

Tags: installation, homebrew, valgrind, macos-big-sur

I'm having troubles installing Valgrind on the macOS Big Sur through the Homebrew. In the terminal I have tried

```
$ brew install valgrind
```

After Homebrew's autoupdate, I got the following message:

```
valgrind: Linux is required for this software.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Is there a way I can install Valgrind?

Comment: Theres definately something *very* cooked going on if Homebrew is somehow surfacing *LINUX* apps. I mean, its probably not malicious, but I'd have to question how someone managed to package a brew app without testing that it actually runs on macos at all.

Comment: Yeah it's kind of a recent homebrew thing, it has some linux support now too :)

Answer (score 7):

Roughly your only hope is [here](https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/tree/feature/macos_11pp), a work in progress.

```
brew tap LouisBrunner/valgrind
brew install --HEAD LouisBrunner/valgrind/valgrind
```

Comment: Anybody get this to work?

Comment: This option resulted with: fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now for me on BigSur 11.7.1

Answer (score 5):

I’d say Valgrind is a lost cause on macOS. Try looking into Address/Leak Sanitizer. Note that Apple Clang does not support leak checking, so you’ll have to grab llvm off Brew instead. If you use `-fsanitize=address`, you’ll also have to prepend `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1` on macOS.

Comment: Well it would help if Apple could contribute some resources.

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind is not supported by Big Sur, but you can try this

```
brew tap LouisBrunner/valgrind
brew install --HEAD LouisBrunner/valgrind/valgrind
```

or a **better** option
in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake -> Cmake options
use

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=ASAN -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
```

and
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try leaks. I don't know how it compares to valgrind in terms of features, but it's enough for me rn.

```
leaks -atExit -- ./path/to/binary
```