# How does QProcess manages the resources when started?

Tags: qt, c++11, memory-leaks, qt5, qprocess

### Context

I'm trying to implement a sort-of orchestrator pattern for our applications.

Basically, we have three different and independent applications developped in Qt that communicate with each other using Web Socket. We'll call them "core", "business" and "ui". This is a flexibility aim as we can simply develop a new application in a more suiting technology and connect it to the others via the same communication protocole.

Now the idea is to have a simple launcher that allows us to specify which part to start. We launch this "orchestrator-like" application and it starts all required processes from a configuration file.

Everything is done in Qt currently (QML for the UI interfaces).

---

### Initial Issue

I've made a custom class oriented towards reading the configuration file, preparing the processes, and starting them with their respective arguments.

This uses a `std::map` of `QProcess` related to their name in the configuration file and launch them using `QProcess::start(<process_path>)` method.

The catch is that everything went smoothly until recently. The sub processes are started and runs perfectly ; everything goes on as normal until we reach some point were the "ui" part crashes (usually an **LLVM memory error** or **vector:: length error**).

At first we thought about a memory leak or a code error but after much debugging we found that the application had no error whatsoever when we ran each part individually (without using the custom orchestrator class).

---

### Question / Concerns

So, our question is: could it be that the `QProcess:start()` method actually shares the same stack with its parent? Three processes having the same parent, it would not be surprising than a vector of ~500 elements stored in each application can exceed the stack size when returned.

### Information

We use MacOS Big Sur, IDE is Qt Creator, using Qt 5.15.0 and C++11.

Tried using valgrind but as read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931093/valgrind-and-macos-big-sur) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075833/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-big-sur), this seems a dead-end for now. The errors below were seen in the .crash file following the application exit.

- `libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector`
- `ui(2503,0x108215e00) malloc: can't allocate region :*** mach_vm_map(size=140280206704640, flags: 100) failed (error code=3) ui(2503,0x108215e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug LLVM ERROR: out of memory`

Also tried to redirects or completly remove the application's output. First changing the `setProcessChannelMode` when starting the application, then with `startDetached` instead of start. Then, commented my Log method dumping log info into the corresponding Qt output (info/warning/critical/fatal/debug).

As suggested by @stanislav888, we could rewrite the application manager part in bash scripts and it would probably do the trick but I'd like to understand the root issue to avoid future mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bad design. Application running and orchestrating through bash or PowerShell script looks much more better.
But anyway.

1. You could try to suppress orchestrated applications output and see what happen. The programs output might flood memory and make crash.
2. You must check what particular trouble cause the crash. Use memory "coredump" and system error messages to understand the all problem details.
   I sure the community need that details. Because "оut of memory", "stack depth exceeded" and same errors make big difference.
3. Try to write bash or PowerShell script which does the same workflow as the Qt application. Hope it is not hard. But it will help you to figure out the issue.
   At least you can run this script from the application.

Comment: 1. I already tried to start the QProcess using startDetached instead and tried different ProcessChannelModes to redirect applications output but the issue persists.
2. We use MacOS Big Sur so even LouisBrunner's valgrind for macos does not work. I usually try to find the issue using the coredump displayed after the crash (TIL that every crash is stored, thanks) but nothing more than what I said :  LLVM ERROR: out of memory or std::length_error: vector (apparently the error is random) when returning std::string.
3. This is our last solution indeed, just want to know if there is a workaround.

Comment: Also, genuine question, why would it be a bad design to manage the applications through a small Qt app instead of bash scripts ?

Comment: It looks like you break application's memory with some wrong C\C++ code. Try the next thing. Run with your Qt application common commands with large output like 'cat /dev/urandom' instead of your programs. This example is for Linux but hope you can find same command in MacOS. That will help you to move bit closer to the solution. 
Also, try suppress the applications output at all with command line or by C++ code. And run the solution in that case. That will let you bit more evidence. 
I'm sorry I can't let you a complete solution at the moment. Because you can't let  community call stack(s).

Comment: >> "genuine question": 
Services("core", "business" ) must start with system services. UI applications must start by an end user. It is the clear way which is to be easy supported by end user's administrators. In that case you start all of them by UI application. Probably you need one UI application for every case. But I don't stand against this approach so hard. Because(for example) most of WYSIWYG code editors run developer tools(gcc, clang, ld) this way. Maybe you have a right case like this.